# merge two daily time series after summarising on shifted hours

Tags: r, date, timestamp, time-series, aggregate

I have a measurement (for instance solar radiation) indexed with a datetime variable, at an hourly timestamp. What I want to do is to sum the measurement value for each day of the year, and match this to another source of data also at daily scale (let's say mean outdoor temperature).

Although, the second source of data is already **agregated from 8:00am to 8:00am the next day**. I know how to summarise my first variable by standard day, but I need to do it from 8 to 8 in order to match both measurements.

An example of my data

```
set.seed(1L) # to create reproducible data
hourly = data.frame(datetime = seq(from = lubridate::ymd_hm("2017-01-01 01:00"), 
                                   length.out = 168, by = "hour"),
                    value = rpois(168, 10))
daily = data.frame(datetime = seq(from=as.Date("2017-01-01"), length.out = 31, by="day"),
                   value=rnorm(31))
```

Comment: You can shift the timestamps by 8 hours and convert to date, i.e., `hourly$date <- as.Date(hourly$datetime - lubridate::hours(8))`

Comment: interessing idea to substract hours, I didn't know of this. and then you do the grouping on the new date?

Comment: Yes, you do the grouping by the new date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164588/merge-two-daily-time-series-after-summarising-on-shifted-hours#comment79292237_46164588) into an answer, it's worth to note that the OP has emphasized the words **aggregated from 8:00am to 8:00am the next day**.

#### Mapping not aligned 24 hour periods to dates

If a 24 hour period is *not* aligned with midnight, i.e., does *not* extend from 00:00 to 24:00 but starts and ends sometime during the day, it is *ambiguous* which date is associated with that period.

We can take either

1. the date of the day on which the period starts,
2. the date of the day on which the period ends, or
3. the date of the day which contains the majority of hours of the period.

Just to illustrate the difference:

```
# timestamps: 9 am, 10pm, 7 am next day 
x <- lubridate::ymd_hm(c("2017-09-12 09:00", "2017-09-12 22:00", "2017-09-13 07:00"))
x
```

> ```
> [1] "2017-09-12 09:00:00 UTC" "2017-09-12 22:00:00 UTC" "2017-09-13 07:00:00 UTC"
> ```

```
# map timestamps to date on which period starts by shifting back by 8 hours
x + lubridate::hours(-8L)
```

> ```
> [1] "2017-09-12 01:00:00 UTC" "2017-09-12 14:00:00 UTC" "2017-09-12 23:00:00 UTC"
> ```

```
# map timestamps to date on which period ends by advancing by 16 hours
x + lubridate::hours(16L)
```

> ```
> [1] "2017-09-13 01:00:00 UTC" "2017-09-13 14:00:00 UTC" "2017-09-13 23:00:00 UTC"
> ```

As there are no other information, let's assume that the `daily` data were mapped onto the day on which the period start.

#### Aggregating and merging

For grouping, aggregating, and merging `data.table` is used:

```
library(data.table)
# aggregate data by shifted timestamp
setDT(hourly)[, .(sum.value = sum(value)), 
              by = .(date = as.Date(datetime + lubridate::hours(-8L)))]
```

> ```
>          date sum.value
> 1: 2016-12-31        68
> 2: 2017-01-01       232
> 3: 2017-01-02       222
> 4: 2017-01-03       227
> 5: 2017-01-04       228
> 6: 2017-01-05       231
> 7: 2017-01-06       260
> 8: 2017-01-07       144
> ```

Note that the new `date` column which is used for grouping and aggregating is created *on the fly* in the `by` parameter (one of the reasons why I prefer `data.table`)

Now, the `daily` data need to be joined. By *chaining* this can be combined in one statement:

```
setDT(hourly)[, .(sum.value = sum(value)), 
              by = .(date = as.Date(datetime + lubridate::hours(-8L)))][
                setDT(daily), on = .(date = datetime), nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>          date sum.value      value
> 1: 2017-01-01       232 -0.5080862
> 2: 2017-01-02       222  0.5236206
> 3: 2017-01-03       227  1.0177542
> 4: 2017-01-04       228 -0.2511646
> 5: 2017-01-05       231 -1.4299934
> 6: 2017-01-06       260  1.7091210
> 7: 2017-01-07       144  1.4350696
> ```

The parameter `nomatch = 0L` indicate that we want an *inner join* here.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I should have given the information on which day is assigned to the shifted period, that's indeed the starting day (and as it happens the day with most hours). Thanks for the extensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `cut`, e.g.:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
brk = seq(ymd_hm(paste(as.Date(min(hourly$datetime) - days(1)), "08:00"), tz= "UTC"), ymd_hm(paste(as.Date(max(hourly$datetime)+ days(1)), "08:00"), tz= "UTC"), by = "24 hours")
hourly$cut <- ymd_hms(cut.POSIXt(hourly$datetime, breaks = brk))
hourly2 <- hourly %>% group_by(cut) %>% summarize(value = sum(value)) 
hourly2$cut <- as.Date(hourly2$cut)
names(hourly2) <- names(daily)
comb <- rbind(hourly2, daily) %>% group_by(datetime) %>% summarize(value = sum(value))

     datetime       value
       <date>       <dbl>
 1 2016-12-31  52.0000000
 2 2017-01-01 241.5612137
 3 2017-01-02 244.3689032
 4 2017-01-03 271.3156334
 5 2017-01-04 253.8221333
 6 2017-01-05 238.5790170
 7 2017-01-06 220.7118064
 8 2017-01-07 167.5018586
 9 2017-01-08  -0.2962494
10 2017-01-09   0.4126310
 ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about the cut.posix function, cool! And can you explain how your third line works (`brk<-...`)

Comment: @agenis, you are most welcome. It creates a sequence from the day before of the minimum date at 08:00 to the day after the maximum date at 08:00 by 24 hours. This matches the data you have in the other dataset.

Answer (score 1):

using `dplyr` and just translating the day by substracting 8 hours :

```
hourly %>% mutate(datetime = as_date(datetime - 8 * hours())) %>%
  rbind(daily) %>%
  group_by(datetime)  %>%
  summarize_all(sum) %>%
  ungroup%>%
  arrange(datetime)
```

**result**

```
 A tibble: 32 x 2
     datetime       value
       <date>       <dbl>
 1 2016-12-31  70.0000000
 2 2017-01-01 218.6726454
 3 2017-01-02 244.3821258
 4 2017-01-03 257.7136326
 5 2017-01-04 220.4788443
 6 2017-01-05 230.3729744
 7 2017-01-06 248.5082639
 8 2017-01-07 176.5511818
 9 2017-01-08  -0.8307824
10 2017-01-09  -0.6343781
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: thanks it's really nice with dplyr in one single pipe (although I would like the second variable to be merged to it).

Comment: I don't understand what is the second variable, I see only value, am I not supposed to `rbind` the 2 datasets ?

Comment: no, it's really a `merge` operation, as the question title says :-) I want to merge the first hourly measurement with another measuremnet which is at daily timestep, hence the two data.frames. In the end I want to regress one against the other.